# What is the expected probability of a basket to be frequent on average?

Tags: probability, self-learning

I was reading on frequent pattern mining algorithm and came up with the following question. Let a company have $10^4$ different products and there are $10^9$ transactions each containing exactly 10 different products. If for each transaction a product is uniformly chosen, then what is the probability that a given fixed transaction of size 10 is chosen for $10^3$ times among $10^9$ transactions?

This is self study and the problem is stated in Slide 9 in [here](http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/bk3/bk3_slides/06FPBasic.ppt)

Comment: do you know the hypergeometric formula for choosing r from n?  it will contain large factorials and you could use stirling's approximation for the log of a factorial.  I suspect the probability is going to be very low

Comment: thanks for the comment. I've found it on wikipedia and read it. however, I think the binomial distribution fits the situation, since we use to draw models with replacement. That is, the probability equals ${{10^3} \choose {10^9}} (10^{-40})^{10^3} (1-10^{-40})^{10^9-10^3}$. Am I right?

Comment: yes if you use replacement, sorry I didn't think of that

Comment: the probability varies depending on how many repeated items you have - in any case it is not likely that you will get any particular combination once, let alone 1000 times

Answer (score -1):

P(10)  9990! *  10! / 1000!

= 10! / 10000 x 9999 x 9998 x 9997 x 9996 x 9995 x 9994 x 9993 x 9992 x 9991   = 3.645 * 10 ^ (-34)

with 10^9 transactions, you have a poisson distribution with parameter 10 ^(-25) so the chances of 1 particular transaction is extremely negligible.  The chance of getting 1000 occurrences of a transaction is

P(1000) = $\lambda ^ {1000} / 1000! e^{-\lambda} $

log(P(1000)) = 1000 log(3.645 * 10 ^ (-34)) - (1000 log 1000 - 1000) = - 76994 - 5907 = -82901

that's natural log, as log 10 it is -36003

so my answer is $P(1000) = 10 ^ {-36003}$